# Wedderburn decomposition of semisimple group algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, p-groups, group-rings, group-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. What can we say about the Wedderburn decomposition of the group algebra $FG$? Here $F$ is a finite field of characteristic co-prime to $p$. Can we say something in the case of nonabelian groups of order $p^3$?

Comment: I think that this question is way too vague. "What can we say", "can we say something" etc. - some precision would be helpful here, as in what it is that you know already, is there a specific question you have in mind, what do you want it for, and so on.

Comment: They are direct sums of full matrix algebras  over various finite degree extensions of $F$ (hence all over finite fields). In each case, the dimension of the matrix algebra (over the appropriate extension) is a power of $p$, possibly $1$. In the case of non-Abelian group of order $p^{3}$, there are $p^{2}$ $1$-dimensional algebras, and $p-1$ of degree $p$ .

Comment: @GeoffRobinson How have you computed the dimension of matrix algebras in this case ?

Comment: If you mean the $p^{3}$ case, then yes, there are $p-1$ algebras, each isomorphic to $M_{p \times p}(K)$ for $K$ a fixed finite extension of $F$ ( the field $K$ needs to contain an element of multiplicative order $p$).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson How to get this conclusion ? Please give me some direction.

Comment: It is because a non-Abelian group $P$ of order $p^{3}$ has $p-1$ absolutely irreducible $p;$-dimensional representations in characteristic $q$ and $p^{2}$ absolutely irreducible $1$-diemsnional representations . The degree $p$ matrix summands have the form $M_{p \times p}({\rm End}_{FP}(V))$, where $V$ is a faithful irreducible $FP$-module. To understand this, you need to understand Schur's Lemma and the proof of the Wedderburn structure theorem ( in this easier case, where all the division rings appearing are finite fields).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks for giving me the direction. Actually, I found that for a group $G$ of order $p^3$, we have     $$F_qG \cong F_q \oplus{F_{q^f}}^{(1+p)e} \oplus {M_{p\times p}(F_{q^f})}^{e},$$ where $q$ is coprime to $p$, $f = O_p(q)$ and $e=\frac{p-1}{f}$. From this decomposition, we have $e$ number of irreducible representations. No ?

Comment: I looked again at what you say in the comment above: For $f$ as above, you do still get $p^{2}$ different one-dimensional representations of $P$ over $F_{q^{f}}$  and $p-1$ distinct irreducible $p$-dimensional representations over $F_{q^{f}}$ . I think the difference between what I suggested and what you wrote comes from seeing the matrix rings involved over different fields. I pass to the extension field of $F$ which is the endomorphism ring of a simple module, and hence a finite field extension of $F$.

Comment: Thanks for giving your time and energy. If we take $q=11, p=3$. We get $f = 2$ and  $e = 1$. And therefore $(1+p)(e) =4$, which is not equal to $p^2=9$. Please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: It is because the four copies of the endomorphism rings ( which are each two dimensional over the field of $11$ elements) each give two algebraically conjugate one dimensional representations over the field with $121$ elements. Thus, over the bigger field, we get the trivial representation and eight different non-trivial one-dimensional representations, making $9$ one-dimensional representations.